# Cauchy Distribution Secant Method C++ Rcpp MLE/Root

Tags: c++, r, math, rcpp

I am quite new to C++ and Rcpp integration. I am required to create a program using C++ with R integration to find the MLE/root of a Cauchy Distribution.

Below is my code thus far.

```
#include <Rcpp.h> 
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double Cauchy(double x, double y); //Declare Function
double Cauchy(double x,double y)   //Define Function
{
    return 1/(M_PI*(1+(pow(x-y,2)))); //write the equation whose roots are to be determined x=chosen y=theta 
}

using namespace std;
// [[Rcpp::export]]

int Secant (NumericVector x){
   NumericVector xvector(x) ; //Input of x vector
   double eplison= 0.001; //Threshold
   double a= xvector[3]; //Select starting point
   double b= xvector[4];//Select end point
   double c= 0.0; //initial value for c
   double Theta= 10.6; //median value for theta estimate
   int noofIter= 0; //Iterations
   double error = 0.0; 

   if (std::abs(Cauchy(a, Theta) <(std::abs(Cauchy(a, Theta))))) {  
      do {
         a=b;
         b=c; 
         error= (b-(Cauchy(b, Theta)))*((a-b)/(Cauchy(a, Theta)-Cauchy(b, Theta))); 
         error= Cauchy(c,Theta); 
         //return number of iterations
         noofIter++;

      for (int i = 0; i < noofIter; i += 1) {
         cout << "The Value is " << c << endl;
         cout << "The Value is " << a << endl;
         cout << "The Value is " << b << endl;
         cout << "The Value is " << Theta << endl;
       }
      } while (std::abs(error)>eplison);
    }

    cout<<"\nThe root of the equation is occurs at "<<c<<endl;    //print the root
    cout << "The number of iterations is " << noofIter;
    return 0;
}
```

With a few amendments, the program either goes into a never ending loop or returns a value which is infinitely small.

My understanding of this mathematics is limited. Therefore any help or correction in that would be greatly appreciated.

The X vector that we have been given as an output is

```
x <- c( 11.262307 , 10.281078 , 10.287090 , 12.734039 ,
         11.731881 , 8.861998 , 12.246509 , 11.244818 ,
         9.696278 , 11.557572 , 11.112531 , 10.550190 ,
         9.018438 , 10.704774 , 9.515617 , 10.003247 ,
         10.278352 , 9.709630 , 10.963905 , 17.314814)
```

Using previous R code we know that the MLE/Root for this distribution occurs at 10.5935 approx

The code used to obtain this MLE was

```
 optimize(function(theta)-sum(dcauchy(x, location=theta, 
     log=TRUE)),  c(-100,100))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you [edit] your post to include the R code you used to determine the correct result?

Comment: Also, there no fee or tax on indenting code, and it makes it easier for other people to read.  Also ensure you `// [[Rcpp::export]]` tags _directly_ precede the function definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `optimize()`function you are directly searching for an extremum of the likelihood. An alternative is to use a root finding algorithm (e.g. the secant method) together with the *derivative* of the (log-)likelihood. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Estimation_of_parameters) we get the formula we have to solve. In R this could look like this:

```
x <- c( 11.262307 , 10.281078 , 10.287090 , 12.734039 ,
        11.731881 , 8.861998 , 12.246509 , 11.244818 ,
        9.696278 , 11.557572 , 11.112531 , 10.550190 ,
        9.018438 , 10.704774 , 9.515617 , 10.003247 ,
        10.278352 , 9.709630 , 10.963905 , 17.314814)

ld <- function(sample, theta){
  xp <- outer(sample, theta, FUN = "-")
  colSums(xp/(1+xp^2))
}
uniroot(ld, sample = x, lower = 0, upper = 20)$root
#> [1] 10.59724
```

Note that the derivative of the log-likelihood is vectorized on both arguments. This allows for easy plotting:

```
theta <- seq(0, 20, length=500)
plot(theta, ld(x, theta), type="l",
     xlab=expression(theta), ylab=expression(ld(x, theta)))
```

[image]

From this plot we already see that it will be tricky to find the correct starting points for the secant method to work.

Let's move this to C++ (C++11 to be precise):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

Rcpp::List secant(const std::function<double(double)>& f, 
              double a, double b, int maxIterations, double epsilon) {
  double c(0.0);
  do {
    c = b * (1 - (1 - a/b) / (1 - f(a)/f(b)));
    a = b;
    b = c;
  } while (maxIterations-- > 0 && std::abs(a - b) > epsilon);
  return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("root") = c,
                            Rcpp::Named("f.root") = f(c),
                            Rcpp::Named("converged") = (maxIterations > 0));
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List mleCauchy(const Rcpp::NumericVector& sample, double a, double b,
                     int maxIterations = 100, double epsilon = 0.0001) {
  auto f = [&sample](double theta) {
    Rcpp::NumericVector xp = sample - theta;
    xp = xp / (1 + xp * xp);
    return Rcpp::sum(xp);
  };
  return secant(f, a, b, maxIterations, epsilon);
}


/*** R
x <- c( 11.262307 , 10.281078 , 10.287090 , 12.734039 ,
        11.731881 , 8.861998 , 12.246509 , 11.244818 ,
        9.696278 , 11.557572 , 11.112531 , 10.550190 ,
        9.018438 , 10.704774 , 9.515617 , 10.003247 ,
        10.278352 , 9.709630 , 10.963905 , 17.314814)

mleCauchy(x, 11, 15)
#-> does not converge
mleCauchy(x, 11, 14)
#-> 10.59721
mleCauchy(x, mean(x), median(x))
#-> 10.59721
*/
```

The `secant()` function works for any [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) that takes a `double` as argument and returns a `double`. Such a function is than defined as [lambda function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) that depends on the provided sample values. As expected one gets the correct root only when starting with values that are close to the correct value.

Lambda functions might be a bit confusing at first sight, but they are very close to what we are used to in R. Here the same algorithm written in R:

```
secant <- function(f, a, b, maxIterations, epsilon) {
  for (i in seq.int(maxIterations)) {
    c <- b * (1 - (1 - a/b) / (1 - f(a)/f(b)))
    a <- b
    b <- c
    if (abs(a - b) <= epsilon)
      break
  }
  list(root = c, f.root = f(c), converged = (i < maxIterations))
}

mleCauchy <- function(sample, a, b, maxIterations = 100L, epsilon = 0.001) {
  f <- function(theta) {
    xp <- sample - theta
    sum(xp/(1 + xp^2))
  }
  secant(f, a, b, maxIterations, epsilon)
}

x <- c( 11.262307 , 10.281078 , 10.287090 , 12.734039 ,
        11.731881 , 8.861998 , 12.246509 , 11.244818 ,
        9.696278 , 11.557572 , 11.112531 , 10.550190 ,
        9.018438 , 10.704774 , 9.515617 , 10.003247 ,
        10.278352 , 9.709630 , 10.963905 , 17.314814)
mleCauchy(x, 11, 12)
#-> 10.59721
```

The R function `f` and the lambda function `f` take the vector `sample` from the environment where they are defined. In R this happens implicitly, while in C++ we have to explicitly tell that this value should be captured. The numeric `theta` is the argument supplied when the function is called, i.e. the successive estimates for the root starting with `a` and `b`.

Comment: Very nicely detailed answer. Even with indented code. :)

Comment: @RalfStubner Forgive my ignorance but the line of code........

               Rcpp::NumericVector xp = sample - theta.........

Where has theta been defined?

Thanks

Comment: @PD9154 The lambda function `f` is defined as taking one argument `double theta`, so I can use it within the function body. The definition starts one line above from the quoted line.

Comment: @PD9154 No, the value of `theta` is the one that is given when the function `f` is called within `secant`

Comment: @RalfStubner

Therefore is `theta` taking its values from the `Numericvector` that has been input into the `mlecauchy` function hence the `[&sample]` beside the definition?

Comment: @PD9154 No, theta takes the successive estimates for the root starting with a and b. See the updated answer for an implementation in R. Hopefully this makes it a bit clearer how lambda functions work in C++. BTW, it is definitely worth starting with modern C++ right away, i.e. C++ >= C++11.

Comment: @RalfStubner Thanks for everything, You've been a great help!